# Cordova app has stopped issue in android emulator

Tags: android, cordova, sdk, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

While am running the sample application facing the following issue

not only Cordova app every emulator app has the same issue. I think it is the problem with the emulator

[image: **my AVD configuration**]

[image: **my emulator problem**]

**while opening gallery app**

[image]

Comment: Because the build succeeded doesn't mean your application is 100% finished and ready to deploy. The app stopped, she did not crash so i guess you don't have logs to go with it and tell you what's wrong ? Then you'll need to find it yourself, log everything manually to make sure the new features you added are working as intended and since it's clearly not the case, you'll found out wich one doesn't.

Comment: not only Cordova app every emulator app has the same issue. I think it is the problem with the emulator.

Comment: You should add that in your question then, along with what you have tried to fix it

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2):

You could try creating a new emulator with different settings, like lower RAM (512 MB).

Also, why are you using the standard system images? Use the **Google APIs system images**, since Google APIs are required for practically everything, using a non-APIs image makes no sense. You should also avoid useless settings such as your 500MB SD card if you don't really need it.

Answer (score 1):

Just enable use Host GPU!! after enabling its working fine

[image]